# docker-compose build fails with /bin/sh: apt-get: not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to build the sample app here. 
http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-and-docker-puma-nginx/

When I run docker-compose build:

```
Step 1/13 : FROM ruby:2.4-alpine
  ---> 64419e20d6c5
Step 2/13 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-
essential libpq-dev nodejs
---> Running in 98d4ed713984
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-
get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev 
nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4-alpine
# Base image:
# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Docker image:
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/sample_rails_docker_app
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

# Set working directory, where the commands will be ran:
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Gems:
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY config/puma.rb config/puma.rb

# Copy the main application.
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

# The default command that gets ran will be to start the Puma server.
CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Comment: You seem to be using alpine and not ubuntu. I've updated the tags accordingly so that your question gets proper visibility. Please check which package manager to use for alpine and not ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, it appears to be working now. If so, I will post the answer.

Comment: Obviously there’s no `apt-get` on Alpine Linux, it’s not a Debian(-based) distribution. Use `apk add …` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, I made it work with the following:

1. Installed `ruby 2.4.1` with `rpm`.
2. Dockerfile updated to `FROM ruby:2.4-alpine`. (tutorial uses ruby 3.2.1)

I replaced ruby with `ruby:2.4.1` after installing `ruby2.4.1-alpine_rails` in docker.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla, let's all encourage answers. Please at least review the answers before posting comments or down-voting, if it is in fact you who down-voted this answer. Not everyone is familiar with StackOverflow, at least that's what I've learned over the past few years!

Comment: It is not a good answer @vee. It could end up misleading other users. A good answer should explain why it works as opposed to what was originally done. Most of the answer is irrelevant

Comment: You guys are too narcissistic, tripping over each other trying to make yourselves look good. This has become the last place I want to come to ask a simple question. deleting account. have a nice day